# We change the root category to sub category url key is already exists error

Tags: magento2, category, url-key

We change the root category to sub category in Magento 2

Error is : url key is already exists.

Comment: Why u change root category to sub category?. U need to change ur Root Category's URL Key

Comment: then what do.. i change the my category list or reorder the category list